# UIActivityViewController crashing, NSCFConstantString _beforeActivity unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to add the new iOS 6 sharing functionality to my app using the UIActivityViewController.  I've got some text that I want to share and if they choose Email I want to automatically set the Subject of the email as well.

```
NSArray *activityItems = @[resultString];
NSLog(@"items=%@", activityItems);

NSArray *acitivities = @[UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard];

UIActivityViewController *activityController =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                      applicationActivities:activities];

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityController];
    // the line above is where the error happens.
    [self.popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.emailResultsButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
} else {
    [self presentViewController:activityController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
}
```

Here is the output of the code including the error message:

```
[694:907] items=(
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor accumsan mi eu mollis. Fusce condimentum dictum lectus, eu ultrices urna vulputate eu."
)
[694:907] -[__NSCFConstantString _beforeActivity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3ad971c8
[694:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString _beforeActivity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3ad971c8'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x35add2a3 0x37a1497f 0x35ae0e07 0x35adf531 0x35a36f68 0x361dc7a3 0x361dc52d 0x36067595 0x36434d31 0x3642fe07 0x2990b 0x361330ad 0x36133135 0x361330ad 0x3613305f 0x3613303d 0x361328f3 0x36132de9 0x3605b5f9 0x36048809 0x36048123 0x37bd15a3 0x37bd11d3 0x35ab2173 0x35ab2117 0x35ab0f99 0x35a23ebd 0x35a23d49 0x37bd02eb 0x3609c301 0x1ef9d 0x1ef30)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I'm running this on an iPad 2 with iOS6. Any ideas?

EDIT: It appears if I do not supply the activities array then everything seems to work fine. Still narrowing down the problem.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you turn off ARC? (I'd predict yes)

Comment: Turning off ARC isn't like flipping a switch... but I have continued playing around. It looks like the problem goes away when I don't provide the activities array.

Comment: well, just turn off the compiler flag temporarly. Don't mind the memory leaks.

Comment: Its something like that u r passing string to an instance which actually is not a string. So check if you are passing proper sting to concern instance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The exception says it all: You're passing in an array of *strings*:

```
NSArray *acitivities = @[UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard];
```

The documentation says the method expects a list of UIActivity objects:

> `applicationActivities`
>
> An array of UIActivity objects representing the custom services that your application supports. This parameter may be nil.

Note that this is for *custom* activities; e.g. if you want to offer your own DropBox integration in addition to existing services.

**EDIT:** As for the activity *types*, they only appear to be used in `UIActivity.activityType`, `UIActivityItemProvider.activityType`, `UIActivityViewController.excludedActivityTypes`, and `-[UIActivityItemSource activityViewController:itemForActivityType:]`.

Comment: Aaaaand we have a winner here! +1.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Now I have to figure out why Facebook isn't showing up in the list. Perhaps I'm not logged into Facebook on this device.

Comment: I wish ObjC had typed Arrays so we wouldn't have this problem. NSArray<UIActivity> would have avoided this entirely.

Comment: @KennyWyland: That would either result in a lot of code that needed to be updated or a lot of spurious warnings. Ah, the wonders of dynamic languages.

Comment: They were able to make that transition with Java.

Comment: java also has a different design than objc does

Comment: I didn't understand what code do i have to write to solve the problem.